# How to add item to order in Magento 2

Tags: magento2, orders

How can I add an item to an order programmatically? I know the sku and product id of the product that I want to add, as well as the quantity. I also know the order which I want to add it to, and I can get a `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderInterface` object, on which I can call `setItems` to add the item, but I don't know how to create the new `\Magento\Sales\Api\Data\OrderItemInterface` from only the sku, product id and quantity, since I want other attributes such as the base price, etc. to be populated automatically.

Comment: Where are you calling this code from ? do you have access to the cart object ?

Answer (score 1):

A bit more context would help but generally, you don't add item to Order. You add item to the quote, then submit the quote (place order).

I won't go into too much detail because I don't know where you are calling this code from, but you will have to access the Quote object / create one.

Then if you look into Magento\Quote\Model\Quote, there's a method call addProduct:

```
public function addProduct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $product,
        $request = null,
        $processMode = \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Type\AbstractType::PROCESS_MODE_FULL
    )
```

You can also look into the content of that function to see how a product object is used to create a quote item object.

Answer (score 0):

```
//$order - your order object        
 $objectManager = \Magento\Framework\App\ObjectManager::getInstance();
                $orderItem = $objectManager->create('Magento\Sales\Model\Order\Item');
         $orderItem->setProductId($product->getId());
                $orderItem->setSku($sku);
                $orderItem->setQtyOrdered($qnt);
                $orderItem->setBasePrice($product->getPrice());
                $orderItem->setPrice($product->getFinalPrice());
                $orderItem->setRowTotal($product->getFinalPrice());
                $orderItem->setOriginalPrice($product->getPrice());
                $orderItem->setProductType($product->getTypeId());
                $order->addItem($orderItem);
                try {

    // \Magento\Sales\Model\ResourceModel\Order $orderResource,

                    $this->orderResource->save($order);
                }
          catch (\Exception $e) {
                    throw new \Magento\Framework\Exception\LocalizedException(
                        __($e->getMessage() . " for order {$order->getIncrementId()}")
                    );
                }
```

Comment: This will not change the order totals. So its not recommended to do this way.

Comment: @SenthilKumarMuppidathi it depends on goals

Comment: you are right but I think as a tech guy we also need to look at data sanity which may potentially have an impact later on.

Comment: Also `Order` does not have an `addItem` method, only a `Quote` does.

Comment: @fritzmg yes it's old code, the best way just find how it's done in core code and do same way

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why isn't an answer here. But Magento doesn't allow you edit orders (add / remove / modify) orders after they are placed. It allows you to cancel and recreate the order with the modification you want.

Answer (score -1):

This is simple order create script, it might helps you

```
<?php    
use Magento\Framework\App\Action\Action;

class OrderCreateTest extends Action {
    protected $_quoteFactory;
    protected $_orderModel;
    protected $_productModel;
    protected $_customerRepository;
    protected $_quoteManagementModel;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteFactory $quoteFactory,
        \Magento\Sales\Model\Order $orderModel,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product $productModel,
        \Magento\Framework\App\Action\Context $context,
        \Magento\Quote\Model\QuoteManagement $quoteManagementModel,
        \Magento\Customer\Api\CustomerRepositoryInterface $customerRepository
    ) {
        $this->_quoteFactory         = $quoteFactory;
        $this->_orderModel           = $orderModel;
        $this->_productModel         = $productModel;
        $this->_customerRepository   = $customerRepository;
        $this->_quoteManagementModel = $quoteManagementModel;

        parent::__construct($context);
    }

    public function execute() {
        try {
            $customerId = $storeId = 1;
            $customer   = $this->_customerRepository->getById($customerId);
            $quote      = $this->_quoteFactory->create();
            $product    = $this->_productModel->load(1);

            $quote->setStoreId($storeId);
            $quote->assignCustomer($customer);
            $quote->addProduct($product);
            $quote->setCustomerEmail('roni_cost@example.com');

            $addressData = [
                "firstname"  => "Test",
                "lastname"   => "Test",
                "street"     => "Sample Street 10",
                "city"       => "Somewhere",
                "postcode"   => "123456",
                "telephone"  => "123456",
                "country_id" => "US",
                "region_id"  => 12, // id from directory_country_region table
            ];

            $billingAddress  = $quote->getBillingAddress()->addData($addressData);
            $shippingAddress = $quote->getShippingAddress()->addData($addressData);

            $shippingAddress->setCollectShippingRates(true)->collectShippingRates()
                            ->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate')
                            ->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');

            $quote->getShippingAddress()->setShippingMethod('flatrate_flatrate');
            $quote->setPaymentMethod('checkmo');
            $quote->getPayment()->setQuote($quote);
            $quote->getPayment()->importData(['method' => 'checkmo']);
            $quote->setInventoryProcessed(false);
            $quote->save();

            $order = $this->_quoteManagementModel->submit($quote);

            echo "<pre>ORDER DATA";
            echo $order->getId();
            exit;

            exit;
        } catch (\Exception $ex) {
            echo $ex->getMessage();
            exit;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: No, this is not what I was asking for. Please read the title of the question, I want to add product to existing order, not create new order.